# What is wrong with urllib.request.Request(url=,data)

Tags: python-3.x

I test the code from http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html on my computer(Ubuntu 10.04 and python 3.2)

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url='https://localhost/cgi-bin/test.cgi',
... data=b'This data is passed to stdin of the CGI')
>>> f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
Got Data: "This data is passed to stdin of the CGI"
```

use the server

```
python3 -m http.server
```

get message as the following when urlopen(req):

```
......
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:390: error:140770FC:SSLroutines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
......
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:390: error:140770FC:SSL     routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol>
```

Any suggestion?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

SSL adds encryption to the basic communication which happens over HTTP. This means that a normal connection will see it as crud data unless you use the [SSL](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html) library.

Comment: Thanks for answering.Now my code as: url='https://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.cgi'; handler=urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(url); opener=urllib.request.build_opener(handler); f = opener.open(url,data=b'This data is passed to stdin of CGI').But error message as:"urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 501: Unsupported method ('POST')"

Comment: Sorry,I know for now,it is my faults.

Comment: So, what is the answer? You can post it as a separate answer on this post. I came here looking for a solution, but could not find any.

Comment: @joar You must add a variable into the opener, in this case called handler. Previously, you created the handler with urllib.request.HTTPSHandler(url) instead of simple use urllib.request(url).

Comment: But i don't see the httpshandler anyway... on the docs https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html.